# Selecting all Cite references using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Supposing I had the following HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        I liked the book <cite>Catcher In The Rye</cite>.
        I also liked the book <cite>The Great Gatsby</cite>.
    </body>
</html>
```

What I would like to know is if there is a way to select all the strings in between the `<cite>` and `</cite>` tags? What I am trying to do is add a css style to all text in between the `cite` tags. I know I could add a common `class` attribute to each one and select them using the class name, but there is a lot and I would hate to add it to each one. Does jQuery have a selector for `cite` tags?

Comment: Instead of using JavaScript for this case, you can in your IDE find and replace the word `<cite>` with `<cite class='something'>`. Most of the IDEs have this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("cite")` should get all instances.

In jQuery, there are three main selectors:

1. By tag name:  $("cite")
2. By class: $(".someClass")
3. By ID: $("#SomeID")

A good way to think of it is "how would I go about defining a CSS definition to style one or more elements"?  Generally that answer will give you a good selector to use in jQuery.

In your case, you could iterate over each CITE element and get the text/html like so:

```
$("cite").each(function() {
  var theText = $(this).text();  // example to get text
  var theHtml = $(this).html();  // example to get html
  // do whatever you want with these values
});
```

Comment: Wow really? That simple? lol. I will try this out. Thank you Brad

Comment: You can do any CSS selector (and a few more) in jQuery. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 1):

This selector should select all `cite` tags in the document; `$('cite')`

You might use it this way;
`$('cite').addClass('myCustomCssClass');`

See http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/

Answer (score 0):

```
one liner

$('cite').addClass('yourclass').css({'height':'20px','width':'10px'});
```

and so on